# Comparing the value of 2 strings

Tags: c#

Hi this might seem complicated with little context but i have a variable called "text" which holds the name of the active window eg Chrome. Problem is it will change after i click on any window eg it will be Chrome 10 times in a row when i click 10 times as appose to only changing when coming from a new window.

To overcome this i thought of making a string called "lastwindow" to hold on the text of the last window i was on and the when its about to display "text" it will see if its the same as "lastwindow", if not, add it to the big text box.

After testing, both of the variables hold the same string but it still adds itself to the text box when i put it under the else bit.

```
            try
        {
            if (GetWindowText(hwnd, text, Capacity) > 0)
            {
                if (ActiveWindowName != text.ToString())
                {
                    string compare = text.ToString();
                    if (LastWindow.Equals(compare))
                    {
                        TxtBody.Text += "same";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        TxtBody.Text += "<br><font color = purple>[" +
                            text.ToString() + "]</font><br>";
                        LastWindow = text.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        catch {}
```

Comment: When you put breakpoint at line                                                                if (LastWindow.Equals(compare)), what is value of LastWindow and compare?

Comment: on its first run, lastwindows contains nothing and compare contains "visual studio". if i click on visual studio forcing it to run again, they are both the same

Comment: `catch {}` is your private path to hell — **do not** use pokémon exception handling.

Comment: i need a catch with my try, i think i just realised what im doing wrong hold on

Answer (score 0):

Just found out whats wrong, i was declaring lastwindow = "" in the function so it would clear everytime i click onto a window. i should of put that bit of code in but thanks everyone anyway

Comment: You should probably just delete the question. You didn't have enough information in the question to allow anyone else to have solved it.